# Ajax and Elasticsearch

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch

My code is below:

```
       var query = {
            query: {
                query_string: {
                    query: "RM"
                }
            }
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:   "http://localhost:9200/lelongoct4/product/132827698/_search",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(query),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);

            },
           });
```

The same query works fine in console. But in ajax i am having some trouble to implementing it. It is going to the error message with status 0. Need some help pls.

Comment: You should try with `dataType: 'jsonp'` instead. Also what do you see in the console if you open the developer consoler of your browser?

Comment: if i try jsonp; status is 404.
In browser console it says "jQuery21009807992465794086_1454405729674({"error":"JSONP is disabled."});"

Comment: if i try json,error in browser console is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/lelongoct4/product/132827698/_search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51205' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400."
"No handler found for uri [/lelongoct4/product/132827698/_search] and method [GET]"

Comment: With `jsonp` you need to [enable CORS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2) in your `elasticsearch.yml` file with `http.cors.enabled: true` and restart ES.

Comment: + Your URL is probably wrong, you need to remove the `132827698` part, i.e. it needs to look like `"http://localhost:9200/lelongoct4/product/_search"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You need to use the `jsonp` data type instead
2. Your URL needs to be like this: `"http://localhost:9200/lelongoct4/product/_search"`, i.e. without the product id `132827698`

Then in order for JSONP to work, you need to [enable CORS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2) by setting `http.cors.enabled: true` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart ES.

Then it will work.

Comment: it should be "http.jsonp.enable: true" i think; i didn't find the one u mentioned.

Comment: If you are on a [pre-2.0 release then yes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/common-options.html#_jsonp), otherwise the settings [has been changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_jsonp_support) in favor of the CORS one.